# Can metal matrix composites be alloyed after their creation?

Tags: metal, metallurgy, alloy

I've done a little research on metal matrix composites (MMCs), purely for fun and out of interest. Different types of metal powders are combined with reinforcement materials, to produce a reinforced metal.

As the structure of the reinforcing material is an important factor, would the resulting composite then be able to be alloyed with other metals? If I made a magnesium-carbon fiber composite, could I then melt it and combine it with, let's say copper? Or would the process destroy the structure of the carbon fibers, weakening the material?

Also, what would happen, assuming alloying works, if I combined two MMCs with different reinforcements, let's say, for example, one is an aluminum-glass fiber composite, and the other is a titanium-ceramic particle composite? Could they combine?

Comment: No, it cannot...

Comment: So much depends on a number of factors:  What specific metals do you want to alloy? What temperatures do you have to attain to get the metals to alloy? What is the stability [both chemical and thermodynamic] of the matrix used?  If your were more specific as to alloying metals, relative quantities, and matrix used, more focused answers may be possible.